# Does it make any sense to run an apache Docker container on a host with it's own apache server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I'm wondering if it is necessary to run an apache docker container when I already have an apache webserver installed on the host?

Since the host's own apache is listening on the ports 80 and 443, it has to proxypass requests to corresponding containers. Hence an apache docker container is hiding behind the hosts apache and listening on other ports different from 80 and 443. I think this will have a negative effect on performance...

The only downside I see though is that there is only one main apache server to handle all incoming requests on ports 80 and 443 for all virtual hosts. So apart from this what is the benefice on running an apache docker container behind the hosts own apache?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely redundant to have apache installed on server and apache container.
Docker is a tool meant to make your life easier. if you have only simple setup with single server, and you don't care about scalability/maintainability, then installing docker may be unnecessary hassle. but if you do care, then you might be better by switching to container instead the installed apache on the server

I suggest you read about [docker advantages](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+advantages&oq=docker+advantages) and decide for yourself